# Shiny button needed only once

Tags: button, shiny, reactive

I want an event to be triggered for the first time only by clicking a button. After that I want it to be reactive to the slider input.

I tried the following:

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  sliderInput("n", label = "Sample size", min = 1, max = 100, value = 10),
  plotOutput('samples')
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  activate = reactive({FALSE})
  activate = eventReactive(input$go, {
    isolate(TRUE)
  })

  samples = eventReactive(activate(), {
    rnorm(input$n)
  })

  output$samples <- renderPlot({ hist(samples()) })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I hoped it would make it reactive to input$n after input$go has been clicked once. But it isn't and still needs input$go to be clicked every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve that.

One way would be to store the value in a `reactiveValues()` or just use `req()`, see below.

The problem with using `eventReactive(activate(), ...` is that it only triggers the code inside if `activate()` is executed, which only happens if you click `input$go`.

**Reproducible example with `req()`:**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  sliderInput("n", label = "Sample size", min = 1, max = 100, value = 10),
  plotOutput('samples')
)
server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$samples <- renderPlot({
    req(input$go > 0)
    hist(rnorm(input$n)) 
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Reproducible example with `reactiveValues()`:**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  sliderInput("n", label = "Sample size", min = 1, max = 100, value = 10),
  plotOutput('samples')
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  global <- reactiveValues(showPlot = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    global$showPlot <- TRUE
  })

  samples = reactive({
    rnorm(input$n)
  })

  output$samples <- renderPlot({
    req(global$showPlot)

    hist(samples()) 
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```